# facing Cors issue on swagger-ui hosted on ec2 instance for multiple microservices but it is working on localhost

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, cors, swagger-ui

I have four microservices and a common gateway for all of them. Swagger UI is working on local but, when I deployed it to AWS, it is throwing this error:

```
Fetch error
Failed to fetch http://172.17.0.3:9998/v3/api-docs
Fetch error
Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (http://172.17.0.3:9998) does not match the page (http://svs-2.elb.amazonaws.com). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.
```

I tried to enable CORS on server but these files are not present: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

The changes I thought to make are the following:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
```

Comment: Listing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is never useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying which server you are using, you added the "spring-boot" tag.

If you are using spring-boot, this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) shows on how to add CORS headers ( @CrossOrigin annotation ).

If you are using Apache ( because of httpd.conf and the 2nd code snippet ), you need to find the current active httpd configuration. Which can be looked up by searching for a tutorial specific for the linux distribution.
Often the configuration file is under /etc/httpd, maybe have a look around there?

The "Header set" directives look generally correct.

Comment: its a spring boot application running on tomcat. Do we need to enable cors on server or just in application context of gateway

Comment: It has to be enabled only once and can be done in spring-boot, if tomcat is not filtering the headers (which it should't by default).

Comment: I am using below code in my application gateway , its working in local but not on ec2 instance 

 @Bean
 public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {

  final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();

  corsConfig.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
  corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
  corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");
  corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");

  final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

  return new CorsWebFilter(source);
 }

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't allow any specific origins, can you validate: 1) that the headers are delivered to the browser when deployed on EC2; 2) that you supplied the correct Allow-Origin content for your domains?